# How to sort ill-formatted pandas Dataframe columns?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe with over 10000 columns. These columns need to be sorted in sequential order. Normally this is quite straightforward:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("...*.csv")
df.reindex_axis(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)  # sort the columns of the dataframe
```

For my Dataframe `df`, each of these columns is a string in the following format:

```
sampleFIRSTNUMBER_SECONDNUMBER
```

e.g. `sample42_5864183439`, `sample3_8976711222`

EDIT: As an example dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4, 5], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13]],columns=['sample1_5','sample10_5','sample100_5','sample1_50', 'sample111_500'])
print(df)

   sample1_5  sample10_5  sample100_5  sample1_50  sample111_500
0          1           2            3           4              5
1          5           6            7           8              9
2          9          10           11          12             13
```

The problem I have is the classic issue with sorting values: At the moment, `sample10_####` comes before `sample1_####`.

The same occurs for the "SECONDNUMBER", i.e. 10000 comes before 1, before 10, etc.
That is, `chr10_10001` is currently sorted as ahead of `chr10_11`.

How would I properly format these columns such that both "FIRSTNUMER" and "SECONDNUMBER" are both sorted sequentially? I believe instead of `sample1_5`, this column must be of the format `sample01_000005`. Manually re-annotating these column names for a dataset this size is not feasibly; a for loop parsing each number may be algorithmically difficult.

Is there a pandas-friendly way to re-format these columns correctly? (Or perhaps I'm using sort incorrectly?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html), for sorting columns is better [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]],columns=['sample1_5','sample10_5','sample100_5','sample1_50'])
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
   sample100_5  sample10_5  sample1_5  sample1_50
0            3           2          1           4

df1 = df.columns.to_series().str.extract('([a-z]+)(\d+)_(\d+)', expand=True)
df1[1] = df1[1].str.zfill(3) 
df1[2] = df1[2].str.zfill(2)
df1['new'] = df1.apply(lambda x: '{}{}_{}'.format(x[0],x[1],x[2]), axis=1)
print (df1)
                  0    1   2           new
sample100_5  sample  100  05  sample100_05
sample10_5   sample  010  05  sample010_05
sample1_5    sample  001  05  sample001_05
sample1_50   sample  001  50  sample001_50

df.columns = df1['new']
df.columns.name = None
print (df)
   sample100_05  sample010_05  sample001_05  sample001_50
0             3             2             1             4

print (df.sort_index(axis=1))
   sample001_05  sample001_50  sample010_05  sample100_05
0             1             4             2             3
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. As noted above, there is a slight problem with the dataset:  There are two types of columns that do not follow the pattern sample##_#####: one is sampleX_#### and the other is sampleA_######. I suspect the correct thing to do would be to parse the columns to replace X and A with numbers, do the above, and then replace these numbers.

Comment: What about `df1 = df.columns.to_series().str.extract('([a-z-A-Z]+)(\d*)_(\d+)', expand=True)` ? In regex are added values  with uppercase and change `(\d+)` to `(\d*)` (zero or more values `*`)

Answer (score 3):

```
v = df.columns.str.extract('^\D+(\d+)_(\d+)$', expand=True).values.astype(int)

df.iloc[:, np.lexsort(v.T[::-1])]
```

[image]

Comment: This post was very helpful, thank you. I did notice an error on my part though, edited above----it is the columns themselves names `c1_1, `c10_1`, `c1_4`, etc., not the entries. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. And just a learning question on my part: to clarify, `^\D+` means start of a string, not a digit, one or more characters. And regex will continue this until it hits `(\d+)`, which means one or more digits. The difference between `^\D+` and `([a-z]+)` in @jezrael's answer is that the latter will only parse lower case non-digits, correct?

Comment: @ShanZhengYang Correct.

Comment: I actually get a ValueError with `v = df.columns.str.extract('^\D+(\d+)_(\d+)$', expand=True).values.astype(int)`. The error is `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`. I don't see any `NaN` values with `list(df.columns)`. This does work though `v = df.columns.str.extract('^\D+(\d+)_(\d+)$', expand=True)`

Comment: I see the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it. There are two types of columns that do not follow the pattern `sample##_#####`: one is `sampleX_####` and the other is `sampleA_######`. I suspect the correct thing to do would be to parse the columns to replace `X` and `A` with numbers, do the above, and then replace these numbers.

Comment: I appreciate your help. `df.iloc[:, np.lexsort(v.T[::-1])]` has issues with int() vs str() when using `df.iloc[:, np.lexsort(v.T[::-1])]`. You should probably get the points for the correct answer (as that was how the question was originally phrased), though @jezrael's approach does work for characters